# Select last number of rows bound by specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the below table from which I need to get last 100 entries (sorted by Timestamp), but the query should return last 100 entries bound to the first 3 columns (ProcessId, LevelNodeType and NodeTypeId).

[image: Table]

So, for instance for the below dataset:
[image]

ProcessId 4, LevelNodeType 1, NodeType 4 has 7 entries. I need to build a query which will return the last 1000 entries for each ProcessId, LevelNodeType and NodeType combination.

I hope that I explained this clearly enough.

I can do this easily in C++ by doing a Select all and then filtering in the code, but thats not the point. I should be able to build a query where Sql Server will do this for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProcessId, LevelNodeType, NodeType order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 1000;
```